# Combine columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that contains information about municipalities and estates like below:

```
df>

Municipality        State
Campos              RJ
Angra               RJ
Campinas            SP
Vitoria             ES
```

and I want to combine both columns and create another one like:

```
Municipality        State      Municipality_State
Campos              RJ         Campos (RJ)
Angra               RJ         Angra (RJ)
Campinas            SP         Campinas (SP)
Vitoria             ES         Vitoria (ES)
```

I appreciate any comment

Regards,

Comment: `with(df, sprintf("%s (%s)", Municipality, State))`

Comment: `transform(df, Municipality_state = sprintf("%s (%s)", Municipality, State))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paste0` from base R to achieve this:

```
df$Muncipality_State <- paste0(df$Municipality, " (", df$State, ")")

df
#  Municipality State Muncipality_State
#1       Campos    RJ       Campos (RJ)
#2        Angra    RJ        Angra (RJ)
#3     Campinas    SP     Campinas (SP)
#4      Vitoria    ES      Vitoria (ES)
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(Municipality = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Angra", "Campinas", "Campos", "Vitoria"), class = "factor"), State = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("ES", "RJ", "SP"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
df <- read_table("Municipality        State
 Campos              RJ
 Angra               RJ
 Campinas            SP
 Vitoria             ES")
 df %>%
   mutate(Municipality_State = glue::glue("{Municipality} ({State})"))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Municipality State Municipality_State
  <chr>        <chr> <glue>            
1 Campos       RJ    Campos (RJ)       
2 Angra        RJ    Angra (RJ)        
3 Campinas     SP    Campinas (SP)     
4 Vitoria      ES    Vitoria (ES)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
df$Municipality_State <- paste0(df$Municipality, " (", df$State, ")")
```

RESULTS:

```
Municipality <- c('Campos','Angra','Campinas','Vitoria')
State <- c('RJ','RJ','SP','ES')
df <- data.frame(Municipality, State)
df$Municipality_State <- paste0(df$Municipality, " (", df$State, ")")
df
  Municipality State Municipality_State
1       Campos    RJ        Campos (RJ)
2        Angra    RJ         Angra (RJ)
3     Campinas    SP      Campinas (SP)
4      Vitoria    ES       Vitoria (ES)
```